# fila em c duvida

Tags: c

tendo o codigo da fila
preciso remover valor e posicao ambos escolhidos pelo usuário

```
typedef struct reg {
   int         conteudo; 
   struct reg *prox;
} celula;

// Tira um elemento da fila fi e devolve
// o conteudo do elemento removido.
// SupÃµe que a fila nÃ£o estÃ¡ vazia.

int busca_Remove (celula *fi,int num) {
   int x;
   celula *p;
   p = fi->prox;  // o primeiro da fila

   x = p->conteudo;
   fi->prox= p->prox;

   return x;
}


}


// Coloca um novo elemento com conteudo y
// na fila fi. Devolve o endereÃ§o da
// cabeÃ§a da fila resultante.

celula *Insere (int y, celula *fi, int vsize) { 
   celula *nova;
   nova = (celula*)malloc (sizeof(celula)*vsize);

   nova->prox = fi->prox;
   fi->prox = nova;
   fi->conteudo = y;

   return nova;
}

void show(celula *fi)
{
    celula *p;
    p = fi->prox; 
    printf("\n\n\nImprimindo a fila: \n");

    while(p != fi)
    {
        printf("%d  ", p->conteudo);
        p = p->prox;
    }
}


int main(){
    celula *fi;
    fi = (celula*)malloc (sizeof(celula));
    fi->prox = fi;
    int a,b,c;
    int i,tam;
    printf("Digite o tamanho: ");
    scanf("%d",&tam);   

    printf("Inserindo valores....\n "); 

    for (i = 1; i <= tam; i++){
        printf("Digite o valor: ");
        scanf("%d",&a); 
        fi = Insere(a, fi,tam);
    }

    show(fi);
    printf("Digite o valor: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("\nRemove elementos da fila\n");



    printf("\n\nRemovendo os elementos.... ");

    free(fi);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso que você quer fazer fere a implementação de fila,pois na fila só pode ser retirado o primeiro na fila e a inserção é feito no final da fila.Enfim mas pra esse problema,você cria um ponteiro de celula e percorre a sua fila comparando com o que o usuário digitou.Quando achar você precisa arrumar a fila para não desencadear,cria um outro ponteiro para guardar o nó anterior e fazer o encadeamento da sua fila e dá o free no ponteiro celular que você criou.